# Switching on types in a factory in typescipt

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, factory

Lets say I have a base class `A` and `A1, A2, A3` all extends A. I create a factory class say, `FactoryForA` that implements a method say `getObject` as

```
getObject(typeToSwitch) {
  case A1: // return an  object of A1
  case A2: // return an object of A2
  case A3: // return an object of A3
}
```

I am looking for a way to make the argument `typeToSwitch` type safe.

Comment: I'm not sure you can switch class constructors in this way. I think it worth creating static discriminant in all subclasses and instead of using `instanceof` just use `switch (instance.type)`. Further more, I think it is better to switch class instances instead of class constructors. Could you please elaborate what you want to achieve. Again, I don't think it is bad approach, I just think there might be better ways

Comment: if you comment out case A1, will it complain about A2?

Comment: @captain-yossarian What I asked is an oversimplified version of a production scenario. Its a factory which I wanted to be type safe. And I can't really use instances to switch since its a factory class I don't have any instances just the type for which instance has to be created

Comment: @ABOS I have added a playground link for the example above

Comment: My issue is resolved it was due to an extra property in one of the inheriting class. I will change the question and add an answer to something I think can be useful for others. Thanks for your suggestions people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be using *infer* typescript keyword to return the requested type. Something like the below:

```
class A {
    public getA = () => {}
}
class A1 extends A {
    constructor() { super(); }
    public getA = () => { return 'A1'; }
}
class A2 extends A {
    constructor() { super(); }
    public getA = () => { return 'A1'; }
}

// get the key map types ( a1 and a2 )
type Keys = keyof typeof FactoryA.AMap;

// get the classes types
type aTypes = typeof FactoryA.AMap[Keys];

// build the return type with generics
type ClassInstanceType<T> = T extends new () => infer R ? R : never;

class FactoryA {

    public static  AMap = { a1: A1, a2: A2 };

    public static getObject = (typeToSwitch: Keys  ): ClassInstanceType<aTypes> => {
        return new FactoryA.AMap[typeToSwitch]();
    }
}


const a1instance: A1 = FactoryA.getObject('a1');

console.log(a1instance.getA());
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `infer`, though I would say getting the objects using the type itself is much intuitive but then question wasn't about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with is `getObject<T extends new(...args: any[]) => A>(typeToSwitch: T)`.

It says `T` is something that extends A and is constructible, so it allows us to use a type as value(I am yet to figure this why). Also `getObject(T extends A)` does not work(why only a constructible type is supported.)

If anyone has suggestions or explanations please update the answer or comment.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C%20AoFpI1gRmgUwA8AXPAOwBMtEVppgB7UiIgJwFdgj6WAKASmq1aENgAc8vPgG4aQhk3og8AOhD0A5jwBEOLdNmpUGKHABM%20YmUpxBdRs3adu-W8LET%20MoXYVLVG7VhTPS9oQ3RwE1gAZgsSCioEWXkHDi5JV2gRcUlQ2hTFFTVNHWiQgxRUCMxoADEwJxYATwB5ADN4JNp1PCIASSYiMFJgPAAeABU4qxhSPAB3aB5lFbAWdQgALmhhpoBtAF0BAF4APjhTngh5gEsiYAALFtIJpvFtiYEuoWu7x6Xfvcni83ngvrJvMBIHg4NhNhDvNAWL02CxSNA5oscJ4EfloWZ4YihMiiKj0ZizDiiVCIDCYoSiUiUWiMQs4NEqYjyHg2mA2CAiAyiUQHix6IsAKIsMW8LSvcQY%20hEOwAW1EYCINwARkpoLcRdBeY0muVvKhaOF0PZlW1oMdWYt6sb2rB%20Moev1BsNRjwgvogA) is a link to an example of what I said above.